# What is the different between normal Authorization Code Grant flow vs PKCE

Tags: oauth-2.0

I understand the basics of both, but I don't understand what's the difference between them at the end. Basically:

- Authorization Code Grant flow: Send a **secret key** in the get token request => receives an access token
- PKCE: Send a **code verifier** in the get token request => receives an access token

At the end of both 2 processes above, the client receives an access token.

So what are the differences between the access token the client received from the first flow and the second flow?

Like, any advantage of the first token because It uses a secret key to verify client identity over the second one?

- If they are different, could you give me some examples of when I should use normal Authorization Code Grant flow or PKCE? And why?
- If they are exactly the same, what is the point of the normal Authorization Code Grant flow? Why don't we just use PKCE and get rid of the secret key completely no matter if It's a confidential or public client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**SECRETS**

PKCE is used by the authorization server to protect against [authorization code injection](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-09.html#name-authorization-code-injectio). A client credential is used to authenticate the client.

Some clients cannot maintain a client credential securely. These are called `public clients` and only use PKCE. Typically they are mobile or JavaScript apps.

Those that use both PKCE and a client credential are called `confidential clients`. A common example is a website, though an SPA can operate in the same way.

**COOKIE SECURED WEB APPS**

These days many SPAs use a [Backend for Frontend](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2). This uses the latest `SameSite=strict` cookies and no tokens are revealed to the browser. The authorization code grant is sent from the BFF to the authorization server.

Without a client credential, anyone who can capture HTTPS traffic could interact directly with the authorization server's token endpoint and get the underlying tokens. This could open up more threats in some cases, eg if the token security has some weaknesses.

**BEST PRACTICES**

[OAuth 2.1](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-09.html) is a set of best practices since OAuth 2.0 was first released, in 2012. This includes mandating the use of PKCE for any code flow. So I would recommend using all of these when possible:

- state (CSRF protection by the client)
- code_challenge + code_verifier (CSRF protection by the authorization server)
- client_credential (prevents stolen OAuth fields being sent directly to the authorization server - stronger options like client certificates are also possible)
- response_type=code (no tokens in the browser response)

Comment: Thank you, for such a simple explanation, but It still doesn't answer my original question about the client secret.

In which use case I MUST use the client secret to get the access token, and in which use case I can simply use PKCE, which doesn't require a client secret?

Comment: That is just public v confidential clients, as in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why public clients use PKCE, but It's still not what I'm asking. 

For example: My app is a web server, and I'm not confident about keeping the client secret key on the server, so I decide to pretend I'm a public server and use PKCE instead, exactly the same way a public client used to get access token.

My question is: What is the problem If I do this?

Comment: Potentially someone who intercepts browser traffic can get underlying tokens. This would be a problem for browser based apps. I added a note on that.

Comment: As I know, in the Authorization Code Grant flow, the browser does not handle the access token, but the server (Am I wrong?). So I am not sure what you mean. 

Could you clarify a bit more, please?

Comment: It is about preventing a malicious party interacting directly with the token endpoint. Cookie based apps provide a good example of where the client credential is useful.